# Tile cracks on a convex edge

Tags: repair, bathroom, tile, waterproofing

I am a DIY newbie, and I need help with some damage that starts to appear in tiles along a convex edge.

The corner of my bathroom looks like this (walls, floors and that "cube" are all tiled):

[image: corner schematics]

The red areas mark where damage is starting to appear:

[image: photo of damage]

And I'm not quite sure what to do. I was told just applying some silicone works great for sealing edges, but

1. I'm not quite sure how to properly apply it on a convex edge.
2. I'm afraid applying material on the edge will create an annoying shallow accumulation of water on that "cube", whereas right now the water mostly drains to the floor over that edge.

That edge is hiding behind the cabinet so the issue is not aesthetic, I'm just afraid that the damage will continue to expand and that water might seep through the crack.

Comment: It seems that things are falling off the counter and breaking tile.  This isn't a cap piece of tile so the "corners" are pretty weak.  Very weird setup.  I suggest you move vanity over if you can.

Comment: @DMoore actually, I didn't diagram this, but the counter extends all the way to the wall, over the cube - which is also why the photo came out so dark. Though admittedly we do store toys there so things can move around, but the fact that it now appeared at both corners makes me fear it's not just some impact damage.

Comment: The cabinet is next to the edge of the tile?  The picture doesn't show it like that.

Comment: @DMoore there's a gap of around 5 centimeters. Just the marble counter on top of the cabinet extends all the way to the corner.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. Very odd to have that "cube" adjacent to the tub with a cabinet so close. The cabinet should have been pushed up against the tub and the cube/cabinet gap bridged, waterproofed, and tiled, so there would be no gap.

If the problem were just aesthetic I would say use some porcelain repair, it comes in a bottle with a paintbrush type applicator on the cap. Actually, the stuff dries hard and thin and might actually help with the water penetration issue that is your concern.

Silicone would work too, I would not worry about water pooling because of it. You are actually better off with water pooling where you can see it and dry it up, as opposed to it running off into that small gap and pooling back in that corner on the floor, which will eventually cause you big problems with the floor substrate.

Why is the damage occurring? There seems to be no reason for it. Sometimes bullnosed or V-cap tiles (those that wrap around an edge) crack along the edge due to expansion/contraction or improper bonding, but yours seems to have a grout joint along the edge. The real fix is to tear it out and replace it, and it does not look to be easy because of the location.